# Do we need the [visual-glitch] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I believe that the [visual-glitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-glitch) tag should be burninated, as it has absolutely no value. It is hopelessly broad, and is used for all kinds of things.

Thoughts?

Comment: Well, I'll certainly know what the question is about from the front page without having to navigate to it and read it.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: If you mean that it can be used for a variety of languages, you should be aware that there is a [loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) tag

Comment: @jakekimds loops at very least is a concept that most languages share, visual glichs on the other hand are just too specific to the environment they appear. How can you be sure that what you see isn't the monitor acting silly or a driver bug?

Comment: @Braiam I looked through the questions and found most of the questions were being used to describe lag so I guess you're right.

Comment: I didn't expect this to be so controversial.. Seems like a useless tag to me.

Comment: @HansPassant Shouldn't the question title describe the problem?

Answer (score 5):

[visual-glich] is a weak tag used for a myriad of problems, neither of them being consistent between all their itteractions, and are normally non-reproducible outside OP's specific environment. Is the equivalent to having an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) tag whenever you find an error. I say, let it burn.

Comment: There was such a thing as an error tag???

Comment: If we're going to burniate this, we should also burminate [lag].

Comment: @jakekimds [yeah, there was](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66624/213575)

Comment: @jakekimds [there was an attempt to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182849/213575)